# Phonegap Contact plugin is not working for me on Android. I am using phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Contact plugin is not working for me on Android. I am using phonegap build
I have added this in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
```

Here is my code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready

function onDeviceReady() {
    // specify contact search criteria
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName"];   // return contact.displayName field


    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        alert(contacts[i].displayName);
    }
};

// onError: Failed to get the contacts

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Can any one help me what can be the reason?

I also need the fetch the contacts of a particular group. I couldn't anywhere in the documentation. Is it supported in any of the available contact plugins?

Comment: is there any particular error you get? Does the `alert('onError')` fire?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: Actually neither success function nor error function is getting executed.

Comment: Is deviceready firing? Try adding an alert within onDeviceReady function

Comment: Yes deviceready is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scope to the callbacks: `onSuccess` and `onError` in your contact function call. Use your app's main scope `app` or whatever you set it.

```
navigator.contacts.find(filter, app.onSuccess, app.onError, options);
```

Comment: It worked. I changes the order in which I was passing the parameter.  navigator.contacts.find(onSuccess, onError, filter, options);